# Proxychains : What is the technique used?

Tags: linux, proxy, dns

In direct proxy youtube is blocked in my school. But through proxychains, every blocked site is accessible. What is the technique used in it?

Answer (score 0):

`proxychains` sends all request to destination server even dns queries.
maby `direct proxy` cannot resolve youtube.

note: dns queries convert hostname to ip address.